# custom ISO for school lab

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, iso

We are shifting our MS windows lab to Linux. 
I want to set up a custom ISO with our required software and remove unwanted software from ISO. This may help us in saving internet bandwidth and time in setting the same software for our lab PCs. 
Ansible can install all required software but it is using the internet,

thanks

Comment: What is your question? What have you done and what help do you need? What computers are you using (brand name and model)?

Comment: You could also see:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization  Which still works with newer ISOs.

Comment: There are many scripts that spin an ISO from a currently installed system (eg. Makulu Linux forked a prior script that they modified to simplify creation of their own spin of a modified Ubuntu system). Why not grab one of these

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Windows client or Windows Server installed? If you have Windows 10, which version is it? Home? Pro? 
If you have Windows 10, here is a link to info about installing Hyper-V:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v
With Hyper-V, you can just create a Linux virtual machine with the desired software and share it with other computers that have Hyper-V installed. No need to create a new .ISO file or change operating systems.

Comment: We have windows 10 on i7 systems. We are planning to use Linux as base OS and winodows in VM.

Answer (score 0):

If the computers are similar enough, you can create an installed master system and clone that system to the other computers. It is much easier than to create a custom iso file. Instead you can create a cloned image, and use that to transfer the system to the other computers.

Installed Ubuntu systems are much more portable between computers than Windows, but there are limits depending on the hardware drivers. It some computers need proprietary drivers there may be problems.

Anyway, have a look at Ubuntu OEM systems, described at the following link,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview)

Comment: Thank you, the institute focus more on learning challenges and would love to go for custom iso. this may help others as well by putting it to public

Comment: It is a real challenge to find the easiest solution, to avoid complication when possible. But sometimes there is no easy solution. Anyway good luck :-)